# How can I set overflow not affecting the main row in table?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to create a table in which has many column. There will be horizontal and vertical scroll. While Horizontal scroll when scrolling will move to each and each column consist of both  and , Vertical scroll will only affect item rows. Meaning that when I scroll my table down or up, my  will always stay at the same position in the table. I have thought of two to do this but they both failed. Horizontal and vertical still affect my

```html
    Overflow for title, only support horizontal scroll
<div class="dddd1" style="overflow-x: auto; border:2px solid black;">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Alo</th>
                <th>Alo</th>
                <th>Alo</th>
                <th>Alo</th>
                <th>Alo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        Overflow for item, support vertical scroll
        <tbody style="overflow-y: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>





    Overflow for title, only support horizontal scroll 
<div class="dddd1" style="overflow-x: auto; border:2px solid black;">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Alo</th>
                <th>Alo</th>
                <th>Alo</th>
                <th>Alo</th>
                <th>Alo</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
     Overflow for item, support vertical scroll 
    <div style="overflow-y: auto;">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the overflow declarations from the tags and add this to your css file for the first case. You can do the same for the second case but with div.dddd1 and the first table in that div (maybe with id secondtable):

```
table {                               // or for 2. case div.dddd1
    position: relative;
}
th {                                  // or for 2. case #secondtable
    background-color: white;
    position: sticky; 
    top: 0;
}
```

if you have no css file then wrap it in `<style></style>` tags in the head of your html file...

**Working example:**

```css
                   /* === just for demonstration (start) === */
            #body {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
            }
            .dddd1 {
              margin-left: 50px;
                max-height: 100px;
                max-width: 100px; 
                overflow: scroll;  
            }                             
                   /* === just for demonstration (end) === */
            
                  
            .dddd1 {
                position: relative;
                border:2px solid black;
            }
            #firsttable {
                position: relative;
            }
            #secondtable,
            #firsttable th {
                position: sticky;
                top: 0;
            }
            table th {
                background-color: white;
            }
```

```html
<div id="body">
    <div class="dddd1">
        <table id="firsttable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Alo</th>
                    <th>Alo</th>
                    <th>Alo</th>
                    <th>Alo</th>
                    <th>Alo</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="dddd1">
        <table id="secondtable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Alo</th>
                    <th>Alo</th>
                    <th>Alo</th>
                    <th>Alo</th>
                    <th>Alo</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
    </div>
</div>
```